# How to delete app from Android emulator

Tags: android

[image]I don't see any way in Android emulator to actually delete an app. Under settings I don't see anything called applications.  I also don't see an installed application anywhere? Is there a function key for this or something?  Never had this problem with emulator before but with new OS I just don't see where this is done.  I see three buttons and arrow, a circle and a square. Press them all and I don't see the applications listed anywhere. So next I check settings but I there I don't see the apps except under search with no options to remove or delete data etc.  Btw, I do know how to use adb and ran adb uninstall packagename and it also did not find the package of the installed app?? Whats up with the new emulators? I am sure there is a way but to me it's not obvious. I have tried many times. Why would Android hide such a vital feature? API 25.

Comment: which OS are you using in your emulator

Comment: `I do know how to use adb` then why don't you run search to find that out?

Comment: Snarky comments are not the answer @Sanoop. to this question or life in general. I'll print the emulator specs please respond with correct answer/

Comment: Nexus 10 api 25

Comment: Are you sure the app is installed? :P

Comment: @gitsensible did you try this Go to Tools - Android - AVD Manager and in the menu for an AVM select "wipe data".

Comment: Excellent comment! The AVD Manager approach looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Any app from the android emulator can also be deleted from the command line(in windows).

First, make sure the emulator is running.

Then follow below steps to :

1. Go to the tools directory in command prompt – c:>android\tools
2. Type adb shell
3. cd /data/app (this takes you to the folder where all apk files are installed)
4. ls (It will display all the .apk installed in your emulator)
5. rm ***.apk (which you want to remove, all apk files)
6. exit (exits from the adb shell)